# Segmentation fault in assembly program

Tags: shell, assembly, segmentation-fault

I am trying to spawn a shell using the following code:

```
Section .Text
        global _start

_start:
        jmp short TrickCall

_ReturnHere:
        pop             esi
        xor             eax,eax
        mov byte        [esi+7],al
        lea             ebx,[esi]
        mov long        [esi+8],ebx
        mov long        [esi+12],eax
        mov byte        al,0x0b
        mov             ebx,esi
        lea             ecx,[esi+8]
        lea             edx,[esi+12]
        int             0x80

TrickCall:
        call _ReturnHere
        db "/bin/shJAAAANNNN"
```

I am using gcc version 4.4.3 as my compiler. When I run it using gdb it gives the following output:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/spawn_shell 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048059 in _ReturnHere ()
```

It cannot access the memory address of _ReturnHere. Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is DEP, when you pop the return address off the stack and try to write to it, its not marked as *writable*, only readable & executable. You either need to disable DEP (bad, its meant to protect against exploits that do something like this) or put the text just after `call _ReturnHere` into a RW(X) memory.

Comment: Doesn't DEP mean that I can't execute in the data segment? If so, then here I am not executing, just writing. But as you said, the data segment may not be writable. I'll try disabling it to test the code and then find a way out to get around the seg fault.